# How to check ID element via tagname?

Tags: javascript

How I can get the ID of an element selected via getElementsByTagName? I want to check elements' IDs that are `<img>` elements.

Comment: You could get all elements, loop through them and for each element, check the id attribute to see if it matches your criteria

Answer (score 3):

You can access all element's attributes

```
 document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].id // returns the id attribute
 document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style // returns the style attribute
```

You can access to the id directly with:

```
 document.getElementById("myIdentifier") // returns the entire object
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.id`. For example if I had the HTML:

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

You can get the id attribute by doing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an exemple:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getElements()
  {
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  alert(x[0].id);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="hi" type="text" size="20"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br>
<input type="text" size="20"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="getElements()" value="What is the ID for the first element?">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: function getW(){
        var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]; 
        return theImg;
     }
this doesnt work?

Comment: But I want to check ID for tag <td> in which exist tag img.
For example. 
 <td id="7"><img src="background.jpg"></td><td id="8"></td>

Comment: You will be able to do this: 
function getElements()
  {
var row = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  alert(row[0].id);
  }
</script>

But if this img doenst have ID you have to using TD's position to manipulate elements like row[0].innerHTML (for text).

Comment: Maybe there is another way to find img tag in table cells?
I want to connect this with form where i write position or cell ID and if in that cell exist img tag should be displayed alert.